# PUT AJAX routing

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

So this is what I'm attempting to do. Using AJAX, I do a PUT call, which should then prompt the corresponding javascript

```
def update
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])

    if @todo.update_attribute(:done, true)
        format.js
        format.html {redirect_to todos_path, :notice => "Your todo item was marked done!"}
    else
        redirect_to todos_path, :notice => "Couldn't update your task"
    end
end
```

And here's the associated route:

```
                     PUT    /todos/:id(.:format)           todos#update
```

And here's the AJAX call I make from an event handler:

```
var _id = $(this).attr('id');
//Actual AJAX call
$.ajax({
      type: "PUT",
      url: "/todos/"+_id,
});
```

However, when that AJAX call gets executed, whatever is in my `update.js.erb` does not get executed.

`update.js.erb`

```
<% if @todo.valid? %>
    console.log("in here");
    $(".todones").prepend('<li>hello</li>');
<% else %> 
    console.log("or here");
<% end %>
```

And I get a: `error 500 internal server error`, server log below:

```
Started PUT "/todos/264?_method=PUT" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-03-18 14:25:11 -0400
Processing by TodosController#update as */*
  Parameters: {"id"=>"264"}
  [1m[36mTodo Load (11.8ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "todos".* FROM "todos" WHERE "todos"."id" = ? LIMIT 1[0m  [["id", "264"]]
  [1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  begin transaction
  [1m[36mSQL (0.4ms)[0m  [1mUPDATE "todos" SET "done" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "todos"."id" = 264[0m  [["done", true], ["updated_at", Tue, 18 Mar 2014 18:25:11 UTC +00:00]]
  [1m[35m (1.0ms)[0m  commit transaction
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 17ms

ArgumentError (too few arguments):
  app/controllers/todos_controller.rb:34:in `format'
  app/controllers/todos_controller.rb:34:in `update'
```

What's going wrong - and how do I fix it?

Comment: Can you post the stack trace from your error? It should be in the server log at log/development.log. Also, doing type: 'PUT' may not work, you might have to use the Rails workaround of passing _method=PUT in the query string: url: "/todos/"+ _id +"?_method=PUT"

Comment: @diego.greyrobot I tried your latter suggestion, that did not work. Here are the server logs though! http://ideone.com/zwPDFf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the stack trace in your log, the problem lies here:

```
app/controllers/todos_controller.rb:34:in `format'
```

This is because you're missing the `respond_to` block in your controller, change it to this:

```
def update
    @todo = Todo.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
        if @todo.update_attribute(:done, true)
            format.js
            format.html {redirect_to todos_path, :notice => "Your todo item was marked done!"}
        else
            redirect_to todos_path, :notice => "Couldn't update your task"
        end
    end
end
```

That should fix it as it looks like the request routing is correct and actually hitting the correct action. Now, though, you'd want to fix the controller further. Specifically, in the event that the `@todo` fails to update, your `else` block will `respond_to format.js`.

Answer (score 1):

1) TodosController#update as */*. It should do "as JS" instead. AFAIK, if it is not determinable by controller which request it is - it responds to all of them (html, js).

So in your AJAX request add dataType: script like this:

```
var _id = $(this).attr('id');
//Actual AJAX call
$.ajax({
      type: "PUT",
      url: "/todos/"+_id,
      dataType: "script"
});
```

2) Have you tried wrapping format.html and format.js with respond_to block ?

```
respond_to do |format|
    format.html {redirect_to todos_path, :notice => "Your todo item was marked done!"}
    format.js
end
```